# WHERE NOT EXISTS not working when trying to insert based independent on condition from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, not-exists

I'm trying to insert values into a table based on a condition from another table.  Not based on ignoring duplicate values.  But I keep getting a syntax error.  Not sure how to proceed.

What I want to achieve is only allowing a user to be added to a group if in an independent table that user is not blocking the current user:

```
INSERT INTO users_to_groups(user_id, group_id) 
VALUES (1,'A') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users_to_users WHERE user_id_a=2 AND user_id_b=1 AND user_blocked=1);
```

EDIT

I am trying to insert multiple rows at a time

Comment: WHERE NOT EXISTS you can use in INSERT SELECT operation

Comment: with INSERT SELECT can I define the values being INSERTED?  These values are being defined and don't exist currently in a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
INSERT INTO users_to_groups(user_id, group_id) 
    SELECT x.user_id, x.group_id
    FROM (SELECT 1 as user_id, 'A' as group_id) x
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM users_to_users utu
                      WHERE utu.user_id_a = 2 AND
                            utu.user_id_b = 1 AND
                            utu.user_blocked = 1
                     );
```

Comment: will this statement work with multiple values for multiple rows at a time?

Comment: @alionthego . . . I'm not sure.  This answers the question that was asked.  If you have another question, you might consider asking another question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `INSERT` only one row you can try as follow:

```
INSERT INTO users_to_groups(user_id, group_id) 
SELECT 1,'A'
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM users_to_users
     WHERE user_id_a=2 AND user_id_b=1 AND 
     user_blocked=1);
```

If you want to `INSERT` a real query result you can change the `SELECT` statement with your logic

For example:

```
INSERT INTO users_to_groups(user_id, group_id) 
SELECT u.id,'A'
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM users_to_users
     WHERE user_id_a=u.id AND user_id_b=1 AND 
     user_blocked=1);
```

But you can't use `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` with `WHERE` condition because you have a syntax error

Comment: I am trying to insert multiple rows at a time